# Jenkins parallel stages ignore the when statement

Tags: jenkins, continuous-deployment

I am implementing a parallel stage for the "deploy" part of my pipeline, where some environment are limited to git tags.

For an unknown reason, since I put the 'b' stage in the parallel statement, it shows all the time instead of being limited to the when statement.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Here's a sample of my Jenkinsfile:

```
    stage('Deploy') {
        parallel {
            stage('a') {
                agent any
                input {
                    message "Deploy to a?"
                }
                steps {
                    echo "a"
                }
            }

            stage('b') {
                agent any
                when {
                    beforeAgent true
                    tag "release/*"
                }
                input {
                    message "Deploy to b?"
                }
                steps {
                    echo "b"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it looks like the issue comes from the stage, not the parallel statement.

I solved it by adding `beforeInput true` in the when of the 'b' stage, the stage is still showing but with no step.

It also looks like it breaks the blue ocean UI as it prevents the input in the 'a' stage